# Configure Microsoft C++ Rest SDK to use TLS 1.1 or 1.2

Tags: c++, ssl

How is the Microsoft C++ Rest SDK for http_client configured to connect using TLS 1.1 or 1.2? It is failing to connect because it is using a lower level of TLS that the server does not accept. I don't see how to configure it to set the TLS level of the client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SDK does not have a setting for TLS version.

On Windows, the library is based on WinHttp. Thus the library uses WinHttp defaults, which varies between Windows versions. See [Update to enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 as a default secure protocols in WinHTTP in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3140245) for details. You can use WinHttpSetOption to change the WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURE_PROTOCOLS option yourself if the default is unacceptable.

On Linux the SDK uses boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23 which I think already supports TLS 1.1 and 1.2. For fine control you can call SSL_CTX_set_options.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft C++ Rest supports TLS 1.1 and 1.2 in version 2.10 and higher.  Here is section of http_client_winhttp.cpp that does this:

```
            // Enable TLS 1.1 and 1.2
#if !defined(CPPREST_TARGET_XP)
        BOOL win32_result(FALSE);

        DWORD secure_protocols(WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE_PROTOCOL_SSL3 | WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE_PROTOCOL_TLS1 |
                               WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE_PROTOCOL_TLS1_1 | WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE_PROTOCOL_TLS1_2);
        win32_result = ::WinHttpSetOption(
            m_hSession, WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURE_PROTOCOLS, &secure_protocols, sizeof(secure_protocols));
        if (FALSE == win32_result)
        {
            return GetLastError();
        }
#endif
```