# http.GetResponse() "could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"

Tags: c#, ssl, visual-c++

I wrote a com-visible class libraray in c#, whic has a function to access a customer's web site. It sends a json request and supposed to get a json reply back. I wrote 2 client test programs to use the DLL: ONE IS IN C# the other in c++, 32 bit. the c# works fine. but with the c++ I get an exception when callin  http.GetResponse(); "the request was aborted: cooud not create SSL/TLS secure channel";
both client programs call th dll with the same parameters.
I have not found an answer yet as to what to do with "coold not create SSL/TLS secure channel" error.
I am clueless as to why the two peograms behave differently.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls), but you may need to do some additional research for C++.

Comment: The following may (or may not) be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885085/configure-microsoft-c-rest-sdk-to-use-tls-1-1-or-1-2 and https://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2019/04/08/enabling-tls-12-in-your-dotnet-framework-applications/

Comment: those dont help. th code tha does the web access is not in c++. it is c# using .net framework 4.6.1

Comment: According to [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls): _For TLS 1.2, target .NET Framework 4.7 or later versions on your apps, and target .NET Framework 4.7.1 or later versions on your WCF apps. For TLS 1.3, target .NET Framework 4.8 or later._

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Network Tracing in the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/network-tracing)

Comment: I solved it by initializing ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol, much earlier in my code to  SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by initializing ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol, much earlier in my code to  SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls